# Bootstrap range slider css bug

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, slider

Eyecon's Bootstrap range slider draws multiple sliders on top of each other.  See bug in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/GqMHM/

I've taken source code from the authors site, as well as example on this site: http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/slider.html

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I'm seeing this css bug in all my test environments.

```
<!-- Notice this exact example works perfectly@ http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/slider.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/css/bootstrap.slider.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slider').slider({
                min: 5,
                max: 500,
                step: 5,
                value: [5,200]
            });
            $('.tooool').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <br><br>

            <div class="slider slider-horizontal" style="width: 220px;">
                <div class="slider-track"><div class="slider-selection" style="left: 0%; width: 27.272727272727273%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle round" style="left: 0%;"></div>
                <div class="slider-handle round" style="left: 27.272727272727273%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tooltip top" style="top: -24px; left: 5.5px;">
                <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">5 : 140</div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="slider" style="">
        </div>

            <br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/js/bootstrap.slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @user welcome to SO.  I can't see the bug you're describing, it looks like everything is working OK.  There are two sliders because apparently it's a range of values.  The source code only shows the two sliders, not "multiple sliders on top of eachother."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tad difficult to tell from your question what you are trying to do, 
but here's a fork of your fiddle that I presume is what you were expecting to see.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aq6fu/

The only change was this: eliminating all the extra `html` markup you added to your original fiddle.

```
<input type="text" class="slider" style="" />
```

I am *guessing* here, but maybe instead of doing a view-source, you did an inspect element with google chrome, and copied the **generated** markup instead of the original html markup.

The original markup only has **one** element with the `.slider` class, but the generated markup has **two** elements with the `.slider` class.

If you view-source for the link in your question - view-source:http://www.qualitylink.com.br/slider/slider.html - you can see the `html` on that page does **not** have all the extra markup in your question. Again, that extra markup is what is generated by the plugin after manipulating the DOM; it's not the original source `html`.

If you are calling  `$('.slider').slider({`, then the plugin would be invoked for multiple elements, which was probably not your intention.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Great detective skills, btw.  You were absolutely right when you guess I used Chromes "Inspect Element".. (sigh)